# Snippet with Custom Variables

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'd like to create a package containing a series of snippets that incorporate user-definable variables. For example, I'd like the user to be able to provide a value for a variable called `HOSTNAME` and have the snippets include that user's value.

The [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) explains:

> Snippets have access to contextual information in the form of environment variables. Sublime Text automatically sets the values of the variables listed below.
>
> You can also add your own variables to provide extra information. These custom variables are defined in .sublime-options files.

I've had no luck finding any information on the syntax for a `.sublime-options` file, however, and Sublime does not seem to try to read a file with that extension when I save it anywhere under the `Packages` directory. Is this a typo?

Using a `.tmPreferences` file seems to do what I'm looking for. Is this the only method of getting user-defined values into a snippet? Is it possible to use a `.sublime-settings` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.sublime-options`, actually, is the `.sublime-settings`. `.sublime-options` were the ST1 files and the docs got outdated, **BUT** you use the wrong link, you should always check and switch in the sidebar on the left to your version - [ST2](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/extensibility/snippets.html), [ST3](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/extensibility/snippets.html).

And to answer your question, you need to put the variables in  `.tmPreferences` as may be seen [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3852)

Comment: Thanks, @Vlakarados. Sorry for the incorrect link. The [ST2](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/extensibility/snippets.html) and [ST3](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/extensibility/snippets.html) pages list `.sublime-options` as well though.

Comment: @PjDietz as stated below the pages, the docs for this topic are in draft format, I think they simply forgot to update that part :)

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky We really need to remind them to update the document. Besides, using the .tmPreferences method, how could I insert snippet of the current time?

Comment: @Jason can't help you with that, usually it's much easier to write a one liner in python than use snippets. The doc is never properly updated, there is this though: http://www.sublimetext.info/ this is the best place for an up to date documentation